# PostgreSql single row returned window function by date

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, lag, lead

Given a simple table of data for Postgres version 14 and higher:

```
item_id p_date low_price 
A1 2022-11-01 5.00 
A1 2022-11-02 5.10 
A1 2022-11-04 5.20 
A1 2022-11-06 5.30 
A1 2022-11-08 4.99   
A1 2022-11-09 5.80 
A1 2022-11-10 4.85
```

```
select p_date, min(low_price)
      OVER(ORDER BY p_date  ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND current row) 
      AS previous_low_min
      from table
      where item_id = 'A1' and p_date = '2022-11-09'
```

The date in the where clause only gives a window for the min low_price of the current row. Leaving it out gives me the entire iteration of the window function. How do I get only the full window ending on a specific date without multiple result rows?

Comment: Well, `where ... p_date = '2022-11-09'` will only return a single row. So are is no other rows for the window function to find

Comment: How do I get only the full window ending on a specific date with out multiple result rows?